# Windows Service processing time issue

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a windows Service written in C# 4.0 which uses Microsoft Exchange WebServices(EWS) to process emails in a service mailbox. Emails are read and some data is inserted into the oracle database based on some conditions.

The windows Service is scheduled to run every 5 minutes. I am scheduling using the Quartz.Net API with a minutely trigger set for 5.

I have a question. If I start the service now and it is processing the emails and it takes more than 5 minutes, as we have scheduled i to run every 5 minutes what will happen?

will there be two processes running the old one which started and the new one just kicked off due to the 5 mins schedule?

Comment: What do you mean by 'two processes'? You have 1 service running using the Quartz.Net api, right?

Comment: Yes. My question is, what happens if the 5 minutes interval is reached and the previous one is still processing? Will it reprocesses the same email or will wait for the processes to complete and start new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz will run the job triggers concurrently *unless* the job class implements the `IStatefulJob` interface. This means that unless you implement that interface on yout job class the trigger will overlap each other.

```
// implement the interface and all will be fine.
public class MyJob: IStatefulJob
{
   ....
}
```

Source:
http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic142.html